# Connect PhpMyAdmin to database in server

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I have PhpMyAdmin and MySQL running in Windows 8.

I have installed them using Apache friends XAMPP v 3.1, so I didn’t do any configuration myself.

Currently if I go to localhost/phpmyadmin">http://*localhost*/phpmyadmin, then it automatically shows my local MySQL db and tables.

That I need is connect to remote server(it has MySQL) and runnig locally in my machine , for teh user of one app.

How can I connect to that server from phpmyadmin.
I’ve been trying to find if there any kind of connect panel in phpmyadmin, but no fruit yet.

Answer (score 1):

For rather severe security reasons applicable servers to connect to are not configured at runtime but [in the core configuration file `config.inc.php`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#server-connection-settings). Otherwise a single hacked database account on an edge server could easily expose the entire network for brute force hacking, or tunneling into LAN-only unsecured databases.